# How to set padding fixed in EditText programmatically?

Tags: java, android

[image]

When I change textSize attribute lower than 18sp the height changes. And when I add a drawable programmatically it also changes. What I want to do is keep the height fixed. How to do this?

See below, the problem is EditText 2. I want to keep the height fixed when I add the drawable in Java.

```
// layout.xml
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#C8E6C9"
    android:paddingVertical="12dp" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="#C8E6C9"
    android:paddingVertical="12dp"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

// EditText 1
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (count > 0) {
        editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_close, 0);
    } else {
        editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}

// EditText 2
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (count > 0) {
        editText1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_close, 0);
    } else {
        editText1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't expect there to be a solution to this without changing your implementation slightly. The `EditText` wouldn't ever be able to measure it's height properly without having some information about the drawable in advance.

So a few solutions for you:

**Minimum height**

If you know the height of the drawable in advance, you could set a minimum height of the `EditText` to match it.

**Just use a separate `ImageView`**

Wrap the `EditText` in a horizontal `LinearLayout` with an `ImageView` containing your drawable.

---

You could also play around with changing the tint or alpha of the drawable instead of adding/removing it but I would recommend against it.

As a side note it seems like your intended use case is a button to clear the `EditText`? If so I would definitely go for the second approach but using an `ImageButton` so as to use the standard Android click handling instead of having to fiddle with touch listeners (which I think would be the only way to detect touch on a compound drawable).

Finally if you're using the Material Components library, the `TextInputLayout` component has the functionality for clearing a text field baked in, which you can read about here: [Text fields](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android).

Comment: "Minimum height" - This is what I am looking for, I prefer to use this approach at least in this case. Thank you.